# leaflet count by featuretypes in featuregroup

Tags: leaflet

Is there any way in leaflet to get the number of rectangles in a feature group? I know this code that work: `drawnItems.getLayers().length;` but it counts all the objects within the drawnItems featuregroup. I only need the a specific type of features, for example `rectangle`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate your group, check the instance of each layer and count:

```js
var rectangleCount = 0;

drawnItems.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.Rectangle) {
        rectangleCount++;
    }
});
```